# What causes a stored procedure to have multiple plans in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server-2012, stored-procedures, execution-plan

We have noticed that many of our stored procedures, which involve the use of local variables, have multiple plans associated with them. By which I mean the same query in the stored procedure has multiple plans.

As far as my understanding goes, SQL Server usually selects a single plan for all scenarios involving local variables, based on the averages of the parameter values in the statistics. However, I am perplexed as to why some stored procedures still have multiple plans. Could you please shed some light on the possible reasons for this occurrence?

Comment: Are the local variables being set to the parameters of the procedure?

Comment: Yes, the local variables are being set to the parameters.

Comment: How have you determined there are multiple different execution plans for the same procedure?

Comment: We use Solar Winds performance analyzer and it shows that the same query is using multiple execution plans in that SP.

Answer (score -1):

Please specify what do you mean under "multiple plans"?

- Multiple plans for one call of stored procedure?

This is normal for a SP with several queries in it. For example, select into one variable, select into another variable. Or working with multiple temp tables. Each individual query will require its own plan.

- Different plans between separate calls of a simple, one-query stored procedure?

This is also normal if between calls the statistics on the tables were updated.

Comment: The same query in the stored procedure has multiple plans.